# resultCode retorna RESULT_CANCELED no onActivityResult

Tags: android

Possuo duas *activities* e uma *fragment*.

A Fragment `ProfileFragment` esta embutida dentro da *Activity* `ProfileActivity`, ou seja, quando eu chamo a *activity* `ProfileActivity`, automaticamente abre esta *fragment* no centro da sua tela com dois campos: Nome e Email.

Preciso abrir esta *activity* `ProfileActivity` através da minha *activity* `MainActivity` e retornar o nome e e-mail que digitei dentro dela (de seu *fragment*).

O grande problema é que o retorno sempre vendo com o `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED`, nunca `RESULT_OK`.

Segue o código:

- *MainActivity*: Minha tela principal onde chamo o `ProfileActivity`
- *ProfileActivity*: Minha *activity* a qual possui um *fragment* dentro dela, chamado pelo XML.
- *ProfileFragment*: Meu *fragment* com duas `TextView` (Nome e Email) que é chamado pelo `ProfileActivity`.

**MainActivity**... (código que eu chamo a `ProfileActivity.class`):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**ProfileFragment**... (código onde alimento o retorno com `putExtras` no `onPause`):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOME",  "Novo nome");
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_EMAIL", "Novo email);
 getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

**MainActivity**... (de volta em minha principal *activity*, no método `onActivityResult`)

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
    mNome  = data.getStringExtra("EXTRA_NOME");
    mEmail = data.getStringExtra("EXTRA_EMAIL);
}
```

O problema é que o *resultCode* nunca vem `RESULT_OK`, somente `RESULT_CANCELED` e meus `data.getString` sempre `NULL`. O *requestCode* vem sempre correto (*1*).

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Valeu pela colaboração Eudes... Resolvido, vamos lá...

O RESULT_OK sempre vem como falso se eu colocá-lo no metodo onStop, onDetach ou onDestroy. Encontrei um artigo em inglês ensinando resolver isso com o getParent, resumindo, bem trabalhoso...

...Então resolvi criar um metodo dentro da minha "ProfileFragment" com as mesmas informações:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NOME",  "Novo nome");
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_EMAIL", "Novo email);
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Resumindo, se quiser salvar alguma EXTRA na intent para retornar para a Activity anterior, nunca utilizar dentro do onDestroy, onDetach ou onStop, se quiser usar, dai terá que criar uma função meio complexa com o getParent para resolver isso. No meu caso achei mais fácil alterar a forma de uso do meu app, ou seja, se o usuário retornar, perderá o que digitou, só salvará se ele clicar no botão da ActionBar "SALVAR".

Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

É meio detalhado quando se trabalha com comunicação 
de dados entre fragmentos com fragmentos ou com alguma
outra activity.

Acredito que uma abordagem diferente deve ser usada 
para se ter o resultado desejado.

1 - Você deve criar uma interface em sua **(ProfileFragment)**

2 - Esta interface tem que ser implementada no evento de retorno
do Componente que tem os campos que foram preenchidos.
Ou pode se usar o evento de desacoplamento do fragmento.

3 - Na sua (**MainActivity**) basta você implementar a mesma interface,
definindo no (*implements*) o nome de seu *fragment* depois *(.)* o nome da interface.

4 - Você implementa a interface de forma a pegar os resultados preenchidos.

Veja um exemplo disto: 
[Developers Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

XD: